# After pressing back button session doesnot destroy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, session

am facing a strange issue.
my logout code is as :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String thanks(HttpSession session) {
        session.removeAttribute("parentEmail");
        session.invalidate();
        return "redirect:parent-login";
    }
```

but after logout i get link as `/logout?email=xyz@xyz.com`

so when i press back button am again on last accessed page and can update the data.
email I have set as session attribute.

Can anybody tell me why am getting this URL.

Comment: Do you have proper chaching directives in your HTML code?

Comment: Your page might include assets (images, iframes, etc.) that get loaded after your page is displayed and reinitialize the session you just invalidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default all model attributes are considered to be exposed as URI
>   template variables in the redirect URL. Of the remaining attributes
>   those that are primitive types or collections/arrays of primitive
>   types are automatically appended as query parameters.

use redirectAttributes.addAttribute() to append required query parameters.
You should also invalidate any authentication related object from ModelMap by setting that object null
 model.addAttribute("parentLogin",null);

So your method should look like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String thanks(Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,HttpSession session) {
 redirectAttributes.addAttribute("logout", "1234");
 model.addAttribute("parentLogin",null);
 session.removeAttribute("parentEmail");
 session.invalidate();
 return "redirect:parent-login";
}
```